# jquery validate not working in content place holder

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate

I am tryting to use jquery validate for my asp pages. I've downloaded all the necessary js files via nuget packages. Please see the image attached.
I followed the tutorial provided in http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=310&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1
and tried some simple validation but it is not working.

I tried opening my pages in firefox and chrome and checked the console errors. There is no error showing in console of the browsers but I am not getting any results too. I am unable to figure what mistake is there with my process or code. 
my code ::

```
// master page
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Global.master.cs" Inherits="MIS.content.Global" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery.validation.net.webforms.min.js"></script>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="tray">
                testing
            </div>
            <div id="cols">
                <div id="aside">                    
                </div>
                <div id="content">
                    <div id="main_content">                        
                        <div>
                            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

aspx page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="Global.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CustomerRegistration.aspx.cs" Inherits="MIS.content.CustomerRegistration" %>

<asp:Content ID="UserContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1">   
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#aspnetForm").validate({
                rules: {
                    <%=txt_name.UniqueID %>: {
                        minlength: 2,
                        required: true
                    },
                    <%=txt_gender.UniqueID %>: {                       
                        required: true,
                        email:true
                    }
                }, messages: {}
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div style="width: 100%; font-family: Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif;">
        <div style="text-align: left; width: 100%; font-size: 13px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
            <b>Name :</b>
            <asp:textbox id="txt_name" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div style="text-align: left; width: 100%; font-size: 13px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
            <b>Gender :</b>
            <asp:textbox id="txt_gender" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div style="text-align: left; width: 100%; font-size: 13px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
            <asp:button id="btnSubmit" runat="server" text="Submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

[image]

Comment: put aspx  full code because  you are not define aspnetForm

Comment: I've put all the required code here, and regarding `aspnetForm`, I followed the link [https://forums.asp.net/t/1466269.aspx?How+ASP+Master+page+work+with+JQuery+Validation+].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`$("#aspnetForm").validate({`

into

`$("#form1").validate({`

In [the link](https://forums.asp.net/t/1466269.aspx?How%20ASP%20Master%20page%20work%20with%20JQuery%20Validation%20]) you provided, validation is activated for ID `#formmaster`. In their snipped the ID `formmaster` is used as ID for the `<form>` tag: `<form id="formmaster" runat="server">`

And check if the validation requires field names or ID's. Most of the time it uses ID. So you may need to change `<%=txt_name.UniqueID %>` into `<%=txt_name.ClientID %>`